Optimize loss over pixel values across two 4D-tensors
I've been trying to implement a loss function (with tensorflow/keras) for predicting an orientation map based on a particular paper I found useful. The authors do this by predicting a sine and cosine value for each pixel (on each channel of the output) and then obtaining a distance measure with the following function
θ^(1+δ) = (arccos(cosα · cosβ + sinα · sinβ))^(1+δ)
for the sake of completeness, the gradient of it is (1 + δ) · θ^δ, where δ=0.2
Given alpha is y_true and beta is y_pred, and that those tensors have shape (batch,height,width,channels), I devised an implementation that uses nested for loops, it may work but it's unoptimized and I'm not sure if Keras will be able to backpropagate it as I have little experience with ML.
I'd like to know if there is a better optimized way of implementing this than the current code (below), as I couldn't find it anywhere, so I'm writing my first question here. The min and max functions are used to clip the values to the interval [10^-6, 1-10^-6]
def angle_distance_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    """
    Lproposed = (arccos(cosα · cosβ + sinα · sinβ))^(1+δ)
    """

    batch, height, width, channels = y_true.shape
    cos_c = 0
    sin_c = 1
    for batch_i in range(batch):
        for h_j in range(height):
            for w_k in range(width):
                yt_cos = y_true[batch_i][h_j][w_k][cos_c]
                yt_sin = y_true[batch_i][h_j][w_k][sin_c]

                yp_cos = y_pred[batch_i][h_j][w_k][cos_c]
                yp_sin = y_pred[batch_i][h_j][w_k][sin_c]

                l += math.acos(max(10**-6, min((yt_cos * yp_cos + yt_sin * yp_sin), 1-10**-6))) ** (1.2)
                
    return l / batch * width * height

Any input on this is welcome :)

This looks like a good start. But as you mentioned, nested loops and your used functions are not really efficient. Instead, you should use TensorFlow's built-in vector operations:

tf.clip_by_value instead of min/max
tf.acos instead of math.acos
tf.reduce_sum and tf.reduce_mean instead of summing up and
dividing by the size

These opertions are fully differentiable, so you should have no issues with backpropagation.
Here is a more optimized implementation:
def angle_distance_loss(y_true: tf.Tensor, y_pred: tf.Tensor, delta: float = 0.2, epsilon: float = 1e-6) -> tf.Tensor:
    """
    Lproposed = (arccos(cosα · cosβ + sinα · sinβ))^(1+δ)
    """
    dot_product = tf.clip_by_value(
        tf.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=-1), 
        clip_value_min=epsilon, 
        clip_value_max=1-epsilon
    )  # Compute the dot product of the cosine and sine components
    angle_distance = tf.acos(dot_product) ** (1 + delta)  # Compute the angle distance
    return tf.reduce_mean(angle_distance)  # Return the mean loss over the batch

I did no heavy testing on this, so before relying on this, you should verify (e.g., by simultaneous calculation of both implementations and checking equality via debugging or printing).

Thank you so much! The only thing i changed was the reduction over the sum, to be able to filter out a few unwanted pixels, and it seems to be working! I`ll update here once I can be 100% sure
